# How to pass on the value of a table to a SQL query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have written a query which reads this

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE (Column nvarchar(4000))
INSERT INTO @t1
SELECT DISTINCT(a.[Column]) from @t2 a
```

Now

`SELECT DISTINCT(a.[Column]) from @t2 a`

generates a single row column like this

`[Candidate Name],[Age],[Application Date]`

I was trying to do the following with the hope of to be able to pass on the value @t1 within the select statement but it is not working

```
SELECT (SELECT * from @t1 a) from Main_Table
```

I was hoping that with the above the query would convert to

`SELECT [Candidate Name],[Age],[Application Date] from Main_Table`

and the resulting table would show the result as

```
    | Candidate Name | Age | Application Date |
    |----------------|-----|------------------|
    | sam            | 30  | 1/1/2020         |
    | john           | 31  | 2/1/2020         |
    | tom            | 32  | 3/1/2020         |
    | brad           | 34  | 8/1/2020         |
    | rob            | 35  | 9/1/2020         |
```

but it does not happen.

It currently generates

```
            | (No column name)                          |
            |-------------------------------------------|
            | [Candidate Name],[Age],[Application Date] |
            | [Candidate Name],[Age],[Application Date] |
            | [Candidate Name],[Age],[Application Date] |
            | [Candidate Name],[Age],[Application Date] |
            | [Candidate Name],[Age],[Application Date] |
```

Is it possible at all? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the idea here that you have stored a list of column names (from some assumed table) in your t1 table? And you want to use that string as the column list in some other query? If so, you need to use dynamic sql.

Comment: `Is the idea here that you have stored a list of column names (from some assumed table) in your t1 table? And you want to use that string as the column list in some other query?` -- yes `If so, you need to use dynamic sql`- can you show me how that is done

Comment: You build up your query as a string then execute it. [Docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). See how you get on, post a question when stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with following dynamic query:

point to note
you can't have column name as "column" so change it

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE (Column1 nvarchar(4000))
INSERT INTO @t1
SELECT DISTINCT(a.[Column]) from @t2 a

DECLARE @clist VARCHAR(MAX)=(SELECT * FROM @t1 a)

EXEC ('SELECT '+ @clist+' FROM Main_Table')
```